# Reusing bitmaps for BitmapFactory.decodeFile and BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

My app decodes a lot of bitmaps from sd card, so I want to reuse existing bitmaps to decrease GC work. I see examples from [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html#inBitmap) and [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8) and it works perfect for [BitmapFactory.decodeResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29), but not for [BitmapFactory.decodeFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29). I use next code:

```
private void testBitmapReusing() {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = newOptions();
        Bitmap bitmap = decode(options);

        options.inBitmap = bitmap;
        bitmap = decode(options);
    }

    private BitmapFactory.Options newOptions() {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 1;
        options.inMutable = true;
        return options;
    }

    private Bitmap decode(BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        return  BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/sun.jpg", options);
        //  return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sun, options);
    }
```

Commented code (`BitmapFactory.decodeResource`) works as expected, it decodes new bitmap using existing bitmap. But uncommented code (`BitmapFactory.decodeFile`) doesn't decode new bitmap. It just writes to log message "E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem decoding into existing bitmap"

So where is my mistake?

**UPDATE**
I realize my fail. I try to decode GIF images, but it is impossible reuse bitmaps in GIF format. The [docs says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inBitmap):

```
The source content must be in jpeg or png format (whether as a resource or as a stream)
```

Comment: any idea how you overcame this issue?
I'm too facing the same?

Comment: Did you read my **UPDATE** note at the end of question? _UPDATE I realize my fail. I try to decode GIF images, but it is impossible reuse bitmaps in GIF format._

Comment: Yes I did! I've png format only

Comment: Make sure all your bitmaps have same size.

Comment: All my bitmaps are 256x256, and whenever I use this `inBitmap` I get an error, `Problem decoding in the same bitmap`.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you're looking for directly, but the alternate approach would be to create a Map (e.g. a HashMap) and add the resources to that as soon as they're being called. Something like this:

```
HashMap<String, Bitmap> map = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

public Bitmap loadBitmap(String location) {
    if (map.containsKey(location))
        return map.get(location);

    Bitmap bmp = yourDecodeMethod(location);
    map.put(location, bmp);

    return bmp;
}
```

This is the same way I use when I do not want to reload resources every time. Sorry if this is not what you wanted to do, I tried my best to understand your actual goal :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to implement bitmaps cache. I want to reuse existing bitmaps for decoding.

Comment: As in loading them from SD when they have been read from internet?